# Ignoring invalid object in CSV file

Tags: java, csv

So I got a .csv over which I am iterating and creating objects based on the columns. Now, in the constructor of the to-be-generated object I'm checking a few conditions and throwing Exceptions if said conditions are not met.

Now I've been asking myself - assuming there are some objects in that list that would cause an Exception to be thrown, would there be any possibility to stop going through the constructor of the about-to-be-created-object and simply go to the next line in the .csv and continue building my list?

So in a nutshell:

- go over a .csv
- build objects based on columns
- if an object cannot be created (because an Exception is being thrown in the constructor), ignore it and go to the next element in the list

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show example records and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution. I put the line, where I was getting my data from .csv in a try-catch-block (using return Object xyz) - that way, the program wouldn't terminate. However, as this line is in a function that has to return an object, I needed to return an object outside of the try-catch-block, which is why I returned null. Now the list in my main was being filled with valid objects, but also with a few null objects.

I then "removed" the null-objects from the list in my main by filtering out all null-objects while filling up my list, using `.stream().map(SimpleCsvParser::parseLine).filter(p -> p != null).collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I needed to return an object outside of the try-catch-block, which is why I returned null.

Re-organize your code so that you do *not* always have to return a new object. Trap for the new object creation failure. If exception thrown, skip that particular loop when it comes to adding to the collection of new objects.

Let's make a `Person` class for a demo. Note how **in the constructor we look for valid data**, throwing an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) if not received. This is called [data-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation).

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Person
{
    public String givenName, surname;

    // -------|  Constructors  |------------

    public Person ( String givenName , String surname )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull( givenName ) || givenName.isEmpty() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException();}
        if ( Objects.isNull( surname ) || surname.isEmpty() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException();}
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    // -------|  Accessors  |------------
    // Read-only, no setters.

    public String getGivenName ( )
    {
        return givenName;
    }

    public String getSurname ( )
    {
        return surname;
    }


    // -------|  Object  |-----------------

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return givenName.equals( person.givenName ) &&
                surname.equals( person.surname );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( givenName , surname );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person{ " +
                "givenName='" + givenName + '\'' +
                " | surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

And some fake data. We expect failure on that third line, where the first name is `Zero` but the last name field is blank. Our `Person` class requires two `String` objects that are both non-null and not-empty.

```
String input =
        "Alice,Anderson\r\n" +  // Standard CSV requires CRLF as newline.
                "Bob,Barker\r\n" +
                "Zero,\r\n" +
                "Carol,Carrington";
```

Use the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to do the work of reading our input.

➥ Notice the inner try-catch around the calls to `csvRecord.get` and the `new Person`. If those lines fail, **we skip adding a `Person` object** to our `List`. The loop moves on to the next input from the CSV file.

At no point are trying to juggle a `null` object of type `Person`. If we do not have a valid `Person` object at the ready, we move on.

```
List < Person > persons = new ArrayList <>();

CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180;
try (   // Try-with-resources syntax used here, to automatically close the `Reader` whether or not exceptions thrown.
        Reader reader = new StringReader( input ) ;
)
{
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParser( reader , format );  
    for ( CSVRecord csvRecord : parser )  // Each line of CSV is parsed into a `CSVRecord` object.
    {
        try
        {
            String givenName = csvRecord.get( 0 );  // Annoying zero-based index number.
            String surname = csvRecord.get( 1 );    // `CSVRecord::get` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if no value found for that index.
            Person person = new Person( givenName , surname );
            persons.add( person );  // If exception is thrown during `CSVRecord::get` or thrown during the construction of the `Person` object, this line of code is not executed.
        }
        catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e )
        {
            // Log the issue, and move on to the next loop.
            System.out.println( "INFO Import failed on row # " + csvRecord.getRecordNumber() + ". Exception: " + e );
            // Be aware that if your CSV input has multi-line values, the returned record
            // number does *not* correspond to the current line number of the parser that created this record.
        }
    }
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println( "persons = " + persons );
```

When run.

> INFO Import failed on row # 3. Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> persons = [Person{ givenName='Alice' | surname='Anderson' }, Person{ givenName='Bob' | surname='Barker' }, Person{ givenName='Carol' | surname='Carrington' }]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, however this was an assignment from university, which I wasn't allowed to change. That's why I had to circumvent the problem without actually changing the return statement that always created a new Object. Your method however, seems very coherent and consistent, so thanks again!